# clustering using PCA

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am doing unsupervised classification. For this I have n features for classification and I want to use PCA for projecting data into new subspace and then perform clustering  using output of PCA.  I have written the following code:

```
for c=1:size(feature,1) 
    feature(c,:)=feature(c,:)-mean(feature);
end
DataCov=cov(feature); % covariance matrix
[PC,latent,explained] = pcacov(DataCov);
```

This gives me :

```
 PC =

0.6706    0.7348    0.0965    0.0316   -0.0003   -0.0001
0.0009   -0.0060    0.0298    0.0378    0.8157   -0.5764
0.0391   -0.1448    0.5661    0.8091   -0.0406    0.0264
0.7403   -0.6543   -0.1461   -0.0505    0.0018   -0.0005
0.0003   -0.0020    0.0193   -0.0116    0.5768    0.8166
0.0264   -0.1047    0.8048   -0.5832   -0.0151   -0.0169


latent =

0.0116
0.0001
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
0.0000
```

explained =

```
 98.8872  <-----
1.0445
0.0478
0.0205
0.0000
0.0000
```

explained shows that only the first component (indicated by <--) really contributes a significant amount to explained variance.

Please reply, Is it possible to create a new features using only first component.???

Following is giving me new feature set, feature_New, using all Principle component. Is this a right way to create new feature set on which I can perform clustering:

```
  feature_New= feature*PC;
```

Comment: I think you want to multiply from the left with `PC`, but then, you should be able to simply use the first column of `feature_New` if you only want to use the first principal component. Note that most likely, a cluster approach using Euclidean distance will return (nearly) the same result using the original data and the first PC

Comment: side note: use `bsxfun` to remove the mean. it's faster. Also if you have already removed the mean `svd` on feature directly gives you the result (faster and sometimes numerically more accurate).

Comment: @Jonas The first principal component is the direction of maximum variance, so that should capture most of the characteristic of data. Am I right?

Comment: @Parag: yes. By the way, if you cluster all the data, and then the first principal component only, you should get a very similar outcome.

Comment: Is it a right way to create transformed feature matrix from first 3 Principle components:                                       feature_New = feature*PC(:,1:3); % only first three component